# Message in SQLiteCursor.class while using database from intentservice

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to use database operation in an intent service. However, inside the service the code halts in one line and following message in is displayed in a new screen. The error is displayed for the class SQLiteCursor.Class:

```
    // Compiled from SQLiteCursor.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public class android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor extends android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor          {

    // Method descriptor #8        (Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursorDriver;Ljava/lang/String     ;Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteQuery;)V (deprecated)
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 5
  @java.lang.Deprecated
  public SQLiteCursor(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase db,     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursorDriver driver, java.lang.String editTable, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery query);
 0  aload_0 [this]
 1  invokespecial android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor() [1]
 4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
 7  dup
 8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
13  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 6]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: db index: 1 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: driver index: 2 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursorDriver
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: editTable index: 3 type: java.lang.String
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: query index: 4 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery

  // Method descriptor #25     (Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursorDriver;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteQuery;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 4
  public SQLiteCursor(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursorDriver driver, java.lang.String     editTable, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery query);
  0  aload_0 [this]
  1  invokespecial android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor() [1]
  4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
  7  dup
  8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
 10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
 13  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 7]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: driver index: 1 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursorDriver
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: editTable index: 2 type: java.lang.String
    [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: query index: 3 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery

 // Method descriptor #27 ()Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase getDatabase();
  0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
  3  dup
  4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
  6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
  9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 8]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor

  // Method descriptor #29 (II)Z
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 3
  public boolean onMove(int oldPosition, int newPosition);
  0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
  3  dup
  4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
  6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
  9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 9]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: oldPosition index: 1 type: int
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: newPosition index: 2 type: int

  // Method descriptor #34 ()I
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public int getCount();
  0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
  3  dup
  4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
  6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
  9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 10]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor

  // Method descriptor #36 (Ljava/lang/String;)I
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public int getColumnIndex(java.lang.String columnName);
  0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
  3  dup
  4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
  6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
  9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 11]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: columnName index: 1 type: java.lang.String

  // Method descriptor #39 ()[Ljava/lang/String;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public java.lang.String[] getColumnNames();
  0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
  3  dup
  4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
  6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
  9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 12]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor

  // Method descriptor #41 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public void deactivate();
  0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
  3  dup
  4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
  6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
  9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 13]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor

  // Method descriptor #41 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public void close();
  0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
  3  dup
  4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
  6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
  9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 14]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor

  // Method descriptor #44 ()Z
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public boolean requery();
  0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
  3  dup
  4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
  6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
  9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 15]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor

  // Method descriptor #46 (Landroid/database/CursorWindow;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public void setWindow(android.database.CursorWindow window);
  0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
  3  dup
  4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
  6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
  9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 16]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: window index: 1 type: android.database.CursorWindow

  // Method descriptor #50 ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public void setSelectionArguments(java.lang.String[] selectionArgs);
  0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
  3  dup
  4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
  6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
  9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 17]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: selectionArgs index: 1 type: java.lang.String[]

  // Method descriptor #41 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  protected void finalize();
  0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
  3  dup
  4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
  6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
  9  athrow
  Line numbers:
    [pc: 0, line: 18]
  Local variable table:
    [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor
}
```

Is this because of some concurrency problem?Or some other reasons.What are the best practices to be followed while using database concurrently in an android application?

Comment: Please attach the LogCat output instead

Comment: @mittelmania i could spot the problem in logcat.It was due to a cursor left open. It works fine now in debugging.But while trying to run it in actual device, the application stops responding the moment I send an intent to intent service.I use a databasehelper in my calling activity as well as in the intent service.